# Docker-compose image building error -> [Errno 2] No such file or directory on building

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a microservice and I am trying to run it via docker-compose.
You can see my directory structure below.

When I build that image inside GUI directory using *docker build*, It runs smoothly. But when I use docker-compose it gives this error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory on building.

What is the problem here?

**Directory Structure**

my_project
|__docker-compose.yml
|__GUI
|____dockerfile
|____gui.py\

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  service_gui:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./GUI/dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN pip install dash
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "python","gui.py"]
```

Comment: Do you run with a `dot` at the end (which means to use the current folder)?

_docker build ._

Comment: Yes, I use like this ->  docker build -t my_image_name .

Comment: But the problem isn't there. It is in docker-compose

Comment: Try this: `dockerfile: /GUI/dockerfile`

Comment: It doesn't work. It sees dockerfile, problem should be somewhere else

Comment: try changing this  `dockerfile: ./GUI/dockerfile` to `dockerfile: ./GUI/dockerfile.yml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you normally run

```sh
cd GUI
docker build -t service_gui .
```

it would be equivalent to run

```sh
# in the parent directory
docker build -t service_gui ./GUI
```

in both cases passing the `GUI` directory as the Docker build context.  That means, in the `docker-compose.yml` file, you can specify

```yaml
build:
  context: GUI            # `docker build` directory parameter
  dockerfile: Dockerfile  # `docker build -f` option
```

or, equivalently,

```yaml
build: GUI  # directory name only, default Dockerfile name
```